# Problems installing MELT plug in

Tags: linux-mint, gcc, plugin

I'm trying to install [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) plug-in on my linux machine, and I encounter some errors. Following the readme file, I run:

```
apt-get install gcc-4.7 g++-4.7 make texinfo texi2html autogen gawk
apt-get build-dep gcc-4.7
apt-get install libppl-dev libppl-c-dev gcc-4.7-plugin-dev
```

This command finished running with only the few following comments:

```
Note, selecting 'libppl0.11-dev' instead of 'libppl-dev'
Note, selecting 'libppl0.11-dev' instead of 'libppl-c-dev'
```

when I run `make all` I get the following errors:

```
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:168: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:172: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:196: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:200: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:224: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:228: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:252: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:256: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:280: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:284: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:308: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:312: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:336: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:340: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:364: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:368: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:392: unidentified type `operator'
melt/generated/meltrunsup.h:396: parse error: unmatched ''}'' while scanning for ',' or ';'
_melt-runtime.c:971: unidentified type `std'
_melt-runtime.c:971: parse error: expected '(', 'GTY', or an identifier, have ':'
_melt-runtime.c:13698: unidentified type `Melt_CallFrameWithValues'
_melt-runtime.c:13698: parse error: expected '(', 'GTY', or an identifier, have '<'
_melt-runtime.c:13732: unidentified type `Melt_CallFrameWithValues'
_melt-runtime.c:13732: parse error: expected '(', 'GTY', or an identifier, have '<'
make: *** [gt-melt-runtime.h] Error 1
```

Why do I get this errors? How do I fix them?

**edit**

full log of commands I run can be found here: [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DAJEXg_yQhbWNWaVZZSVRPeTQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Please **ask MELT related questions on the [MELT googleforum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gcc-melt)** i.e. on `gcc-melt@googlegroups.com`; you need to subscribe and I ([Basile Starynkevitch](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/)) need to accept your subscription.

And give all the output of your building commands. What you are showing is not enough.

I guess that you might need to type

```
 make all MELTGCC=gcc-4.7 GCCMELT_CXX=g++-4.7
```

I guess that the errors you are getting is because MELT generated code is incorrectly compiled as C code, and it should be compiled as C++ code (since it is C++ since MELT 1.0). I might be wrong and I cannot explain more, since you did not show all your commands and all their outputs.

I can now reproduce the bug (apparently specific to GCC 4.7) and I'm working on this bug. It is [MELT-SFT-6](https://sourceforge.net/p/gcc-melt/tickets/6/); a bug fix will be announced on `gcc-melt@googlegroups.com`

#### addenda

I just [announced the MELT 1.0.1 release candidate 1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gcc-melt/JaOnYDro4k0/IpoSTYz3tnsJ) which should fix the bug. Please download it and report on `gcc-melt@googlegroups.com` (not here, because I almost never read this Unix.StackExchange forum!) any successes or failures on your system. Thanks.

Comment: I added a complete log.